# how to skip testing scenario for different environment

Tags: testing, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

How to skips scenarios conditionally in Cucumber Java testing?

For different testing environement,different scenarios need to be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a tag for the scenarios and exclude those scenario using the tags with cucumber options.

For example,

```
Feature: Feature 1

@skipforenv2
Scenario: Testing 1
....


@skipforenv1
Scenario: Testing 2
....
```

Assume if you want to skip scenario "Testing 2" in environment 1 and scenario "Testing 1"in Environment 2 Then,

While running on Environment 1, you can pass the tag argument as ~@skipforenv1 (--tags @skipforenv1). if we use ~ symbol before tag then it will be skipped for that execution.

```
using command line, `-Dcucumber.options="--tags ~@skipforenv1"`

using runner class, `@CucumberOptions(tags={"~@skipforenv1"}, .....)`
```

While running on Environment 2, you can pass the tag argument as ~@skipforenv2 (--tags @skipforenv2). Scenario 2 will be skipped.

using command line, `-Dcucumber.options="--tags ~@skipforenv2"`

using runner class, `@CucumberOptions(tags={"~@skipforenv2"}, .....)`

Comment: I am able to skip the tagged scenario via runner class but not using command prompt...any idea why?

Comment: have you used ~ symbol before the tag? like -Dcucumber.options="--tags ~@skipforenv2"